# Can I sacrifice the same creature twice with Blood Host?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So for example I am using [Blood Host](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383193) and I sacrifice [Reassembling Skeleton](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reassembling%20Skeleton), then revive him using his ability. The description says "Sacrifice another creature" to activate the ability. Because I have already sacrificed reassembling skeleton that turn, can I still sacrifice it again after it has been revived.

Comment: "Sacrifice another creature" means "sacrifice a creature other than Blood Host"

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, in this case 'another creature' means a creature other than Blood Host, not a creature that you haven't sacrificed before.

Even if that weren't the case once it move from the battlefield to the graveyard the first time the game no longer sees it as the same creature.

> **400.7.** An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are seven exceptions to this rule: ...

So you are free to keep sacrificing the skeletons and reassembling them as long as you have the mana to do it.

Comment: In this case I believe 400.7 to be a red herring; the question stemmed completely from the lack of understanding of what "another" means. Is there a specific rule that defines "another" to be "other than the card this 'another' is printed on"?

Comment: @GendoIkari I wasn't able to find such a rule, I am pretty sure the game uses the normal English definition. I just included 400.7 to clarify why 'another' can't mean what they thought it did.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that.

Your title here is a bit misleading; you're not actually sacrificing the same creature twice:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. There are seven exceptions to this rule: ...

(none of the exceptions apply here)

So once you reassemble your skeleton, it's just... another creature. It doesn't matter that another one represented by the same card got sacrificed before. It's a creature on the battlefield now, so it can be sacrificed. The only restriction on Blood Host's ability is that it has to be another creature (besides that Blood Host), i.e. Blood Host can't drink its own blood.

Comment: I think the Reassembling Skeleton flavor text really nails the fact that it's actually another creature: "Though you may see the same bones, you'll never see the same skeleton twice."